# Global Exception in PHP

Tags: php

There's this code when I read a book today:

```
public function __construct($path) {
    if (!is_dir($path) || !is_writable($path)) {
         throw new \Exception("$path must be a valid,writable directory.");
    }
    $this->destination = $path;
}
```

This line of code appears in a namespace PHP file. My question is what would happen if I don't use a global space when throwing an exception inside a namespace (\Exception)?

Comment: You would have to import Exception namespace with something similar to `use Exception;` (depending on where it is located);

Comment: If the code you post is implemented inside some namespace then the plain `Exception` is not a known identifier. Therefor you would get a "undefined class" error with such attempt. You either have to use the qualified notation or, as said by @pavlovich above, you'd have to import the class: `use \Exception;`

Comment: Thanks for the response guys.